# Execute commands.getoutput with a variable

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to execute a command in python and I'm giving this command a variable

```
commands.getoutput("cat '" +dir_log+ "'")
```

dir_log is a variable but python doesn't get it as a variable.

Comment: Where is this `dir_log` defined? What do you get when you `print(dir_log)`?

Comment: `dir_log` is defined before `commands.getoutput` in this case dir_log is the route of a file which is /usr/local/file.txt.                                                 It doesn't print anything but it also doesn't give any error

Answer (score 1):

From the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html):

> *Deprecated since version 2.6: The [`commands`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#module-commands) module has been removed in Python 3. Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead.*

So, unless you're using Python 2.5 or earlier, which I doubt, use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module:

```
import subprocess

dir_log = "/path/to/file"
output = subprocess.check_output(["cat", dir_log])
```

The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module will handle the escapes and argument chaining for you.

The only question remains - what do you mean under *"but python doesn't get it as a variable"*? If `dir_log` is available available in the local context, its value will be passed to `cat`.

It makes little sense to call `cat` as a subprocess when you can just load the contents in Python directly, tho:

```
with open(dir_log, "r") as f:
    file_contents = f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

in python 2,try:

```
command='cat {}'.format(dir_log)
commands.getoutput(command)
```

in python 3, commands module is deprecated and `subprocess.getoutput` is the equivalent of `commands.getoutput`, try:

```
command='cat {}'.format(dir_log)
subprocess.getoutput([command])
```